# How do you pronounce "Ocoeur", "Saycet" & "El Huervo"?

Tags: names, language

These are three musicians I like. Ocoeur & Saycet are french, El Huervo is swedish (though the name is more spanish-like), so I guess it influences the pronunciation. I don't know a particular place where I could check it, except for here and asking them personally.

I've read that Ocoeur is from french "au coeur".

Please mention if you know this from a particular source or it's more of a general knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

"Ocoeur" is the alias of French musician Franck Zaragoza. It is, as you point out, derived from the French "au coeur". Since there is nothing on
[his biog page](https://n5md.com/artist/Ocoeur) to indicate any other pronounciation, it is most likely pronounced as the French "au coeur".

Edit: 25th August 2020 : for 'Saycet' answer to correct/amend my own answer and include additional information provided in answer by @Bebs  (thanks!):
"Saycet" is an alias of French musician Pierre Lefeuvre and his collaborators.  His [fan website](http://saycet.org/biographie/) gives no clue as to the pronunciation, so I as a non-native French speaker assumed the final "t" is silent (like "ballet", "beignet", "Manet" etc). However, Google Translate has it with a sounded final "t" : as do the 2 interviews in @Bebs' answer : [interview 1](https://youtu.be/CZw9mzuNOFA?t=19) [interview 2](https://youtu.be/9nhvxPblgeI?t=160)- so the "c" is soft and the final "t" is sounded.

"El Huervo" is the name used by Swedish artist [Niklas Åkerblad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklas_%C3%85kerblad) for his musical work.
It probably dates from his involvement with the soundtrack to video shooter game ["Hotline Miami"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotline_Miami).His [website](http://elhuervo.tumblr.com/) has many South/Central American / Latin influences, so it's safe to say that it would be pronounced as Spanish: "el Huervo"

Comment: Thanks for backing up my assumptions. I know the names behind these aliases, but it might be useful for other readers. One small thing though: Hotline Miami is not "online".

Comment: Edited to correct this, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Your assumption on Spanish pronunciation of El Huervo turned out to be true.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with Angst answer on **sayCet** : As you can heay on this [interview video](https://youtu.be/CZw9mzuNOFA?t=19), the woman on the right prononces it merely like you would prononce it in english (with a french accent of course). And the final "t" is sounded. Another example [here](https://youtu.be/9nhvxPblgeI?t=160) with a better english accent.

Comment: actual footage of  a French person saying the name is definitive, sure.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a comment from El Huervo himself (which is cool in itself).

In short, he thought that it meant "wolverine", but it turned out it means nothing. Name should be pronounced in a Spanish manner.

Comment: I was puzzled about what the word might mean, so I'm glad it actually is a made-up word or whatever. Sounds IMO like it ought to mean something dangerous/edgy like "Wolverine", so a good choice for an alternative ID.